# how to introduce a girl who is friend and not girl-friend

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

Often times I have got across situations where I have to tell a girl that

> "I don't have a girlfriend but there are some girls who are friends"

So I was looking for the right word here or a good slang would do.

Googled a lot but couldn't find the answer to what I am looking for.

Also I have seen girls replying

> "I don't have a boyfriend but **guy friends**"

So , is there any equivalent of guy friends for boys ?

Comment: What's wrong with "friend"?

Comment: Related: [Does “girlfriend” or “boyfriend” always indicate partnership?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102865/does-girlfriend-or-boyfriend-always-indicate-partnership)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no slang word for a girl who is a friend. Usually if you want to make it clear that a girl you know is not your girlfriend you  would say something like, "My friend who is a girl". A lot of girls when speaking of their friends who are girls will call them "my girlfriends". However to say this as a male would probably imply that you have multiple romantic partners.

Answer (score 1):

a **"Gal Pal"** is defined on several online dictionaries as a friend who is a girl and whom one has a platonic (non-sexual or -romantic) relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard anyone actually use this. I think this may be specific to certain regions/cultures.

Comment: @MrHen, that's an interesting observation.  I've heard it but can't pin down a certain group that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

If they are just friends, then gender should be left out of the statement:

> Samuel says, "Sarah, this is my friend, Cynthia."

If the listener is interpreting your words because they are interested in engaging in an exclusive relationship with you, then the term "friend" - said confidently and plainly - should be enough to clarify the absence of romance in said friendship.

Many would argue that Friendship, itself, is characterized by an absence of romance.

Comment: Yeah, but as Paul Davis sings in "I Go Crazy", *"They say old lovers can be good friends"* :-)