# How would you refer to a female friend?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammatical-gender

I was wondering how you would introduce a female friend to a group of friends. In German, it's just

> Sie ist eine Freundin von mir

Which translates to

> She is a friend of mine.

But I'm a bit confused when it comes to these phrases:

> "Ich besuche eine Freundin von mir"

It means, basically,

> Im visiting a (female) friend of mine

or

> Ich habe auf der Arbeit eine neue Freundin kennengelernt

which translates to

> I met a new (female) friend at work

But is there actually a female version of 'friend' in English? How would people know which gender I am visiting or talking about?

I found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133651/how-to-introduce-a-girl-who-is-friend-and-not-girl-friend) question which is kinda similar but does not satisfy me. Is there a word that is commonly in use?

Comment: I guess this is an issue if you come from a more strongly gendered language than English, but why would you need to specify the gender of friends any more than you would of doctors, teachers, or colleagues (all of which are ungendered in English)?

Comment: @StuartF Spot on! Public mention, let alone discussion, of sex is awkward at best and may well be wildly inappropriate in many social contexts. This sort of thing can easily reflect as poorly on speakers who mention *female doctors, male teachers, female architects, male nurses, female plumbers* as on those who mention *black doctors, brown teachers, Jewish architects, red-headed nurses, left-handed plumbers*.

Comment: @StuartF and imagine the horror of a language where the _diminutive_ was routinely used to indicate female gender. So "a colleague" implies a male co-worker, whereas "a little colleague" implies she's female. (Yup, that used to common in Dutch, although I'm happy to see it falling out of fashion rapidly, together with actual gendered words where gender should not matter.)

Comment: @tchrist, if one is a native speaker of a language, such as English, in which these words are not gendered, it is natural that one would wonder why anybody would need to specify the sex/gender of those involved, and to suspect that some discriminatory or otherwise nefarious purpose is behind it. But is one is a native speaker of a language, such as German, in which these words are gendered, it is equally natural to wonder why anybody would wish to hide the sex/gender of those involved. So, what will be perceived as 'wildly inappropriate' here is likely to depend on one's linguistic background.

Comment: @jsw29 "what will be perceived as 'wildly inappropriate' here is likely to depend on one's linguistic background" Also amongst speakers of (some?) languages where these words are routinely gendered, a change is happening (partly because the male and female versions started to mean wildly different things, like a male or female secretary). Even the gendered versions in English, where they exist, seem to be on the way out (e.g. actress is frowned upon in some circles). So the appropriateness seems dependent on more than just linguistic background.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a female form of 'friend' in English. We would make the person's gender clear by adding something like "Her name is Mary", or if necessary by specifying 'a female friend'.

Women sometimes used to refer to their 'girlfriends' in the days when same-sex relationships were not openly discussed, so there was no risk of misunderstanding.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. Im a bit surprised that there is no such word and we only refer to them with a "workaround". Definitely not what I would've thought.

Comment: Calling a friend a friend is hardly a workaround.

Comment: _Cousin, neighbour_ and many occupational terms such as _doctor_ (as Stuart points out) are ungendered in English. We no longer say _authoress, poetess_ (which are seen as implying that female ones are exceptional), and _actress_ is falling out of favour.